# What are some good books on algebraic inequalities?

Tags: inequality, reference-request, contest-math, book-recommendation

By algebraic inequalities I mean inequalities like Cauchy's inequality, the AM-GM inequality etc. I need it for the International Mathematics Olympiad (IMO), so I hope I can find some books that introduce inequalities on that level. While I can only find problems on websites like M.SE. or [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community) (most of which are almost unintelligible to me), I want a book that provides a detailed, reader-friendly approach to that subject. Any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basics of Olympiad Inequalities (Samin Riasat)

*www.aam.org.in/site/st_material/14.pdf*

It's a free pdf document and it is very useful.

Comment: Thank you. That's true. I'm currently reading this note. One flaw is just that it doesn't provide complete answers to the exercises, and I don't consider the questions to be "basic". Then M.SE. turns out to be quite useful since I can ask questions here. :)

Answer (score 10):

*The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class: An Introduction to the Art of Mathematical Inequalities* by J. Michael Steele.

Answer (score 4):

$1$. *Garling - Inequalities*

$2$. *Cvetkovski - Inequalities*

$3$. *Zawaira - A Primer for Mathematics Competitions*

Answer (score 3):

*Old and New Inequalities* Volume 1 - Titu Andreescu

*Old and New Inequalities* Volume 2 - Vo Quoc Ba Can et.al.

*Algebraic Inequalities* - Vasile Cirtoaje

*Secrets in Inequalities* - Pham Kim Hung [Volume 1 and 2]

*Inequalities with Beautiful Solutions* - Vo Quoc Ba Can et.al.

To my best knowledge, all the problems presented in the above mentioned books are solved.

Comment: Do you have old and new inequalities volume 2

Answer (score 3):

B.J.Venkatachala for inequality is a very good book for what you are searching.You may see this book.

Answer (score 2):

With the note that certain algebraic inequalities require some calculus to derive and/or grasp the full context:

$1$ *Hardy, Littlewood, Polya - Inequalities;*

$2$ *Beckenbach, Bellman - Inequalities.*